Linear discrete dynamical systems modulo different integers
A classic discrete linear time-invariant dynamical system (without input) is defined for a state vector $x=(x_1,x_2,...)$ and a matrix $A$ as
$$
x[n+1]=A\, x[n],
$$
and has solution $x[n]=A^n x[0]$ for a given $x[0]$. I found that this also works in finite fields, i.e. in $\mathbb{Z}_k$ we basically have that $x[n]=A^n x[0] \text{ mod } k$. What I am wondering is if you can combine multiple fields/different modulo operations;
e.g. if you have
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_1[n+1]&= a \, x_1[n] + b\, x_2[n] \text{ mod } k\\
x_2[n+1]&= c \, x_1[n] + d \, x_2[n]
\end{aligned}
$$
or
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_1[n+1]&= a \, x_1[n] + b\, x_2[n] \text{ mod } k_1\\
x_2[n+1]&= c \, x_1[n] + d \, x_2[n]\text{ mod } k_2.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since matrix exponentiation modulo some number is very efficient I want to know: Is there an effective way to compute $x[n]$ from $x[0]$ in such a system or is there some extended theory about this?
